# Программирование таймера Assembler

Tags: ассемблер

Стоит задача написать программу, которая выведет сформирует звуковую последовательность (до-ре-соль-ми 261 Гц, 293 Гц, 392 Гц, 329 Гц) после нажатия на клавишу "V" и выведет текущий месяц. Не хочу тратить ваше время, по этому скажу откровенно Assembler вообще не учил. Он проходится очень бегло, то есть до этого была написана простая программа. находящая значение какого-то выражения. Трудно ли это сделать?

```
    .date
        mov     al, 182         ; Prepare the speaker for the
        out     43h, al         ;  note.
        mov     ax, 4560        ; Frequency number (in decimal)
                                ;  for middle C.
        out     42h, al         ; Output low byte.
        mov     al, ah          ; Output high byte.
        out     42h, al 
        in      al, 61h         ; Turn on note (get value from
                                ;  port 61h).
        or      al, 00000011b   ; Set bits 1 and 0.
        out     61h, al         ; Send new value.
        mov     bx, 25          ; Pause for duration of note.
pause1:
        mov     cx, 65535
pause2:
        dec     cx
        jne     .pause2
        dec     bx
        jne     .pause1
        in      al, 61h         ; Turn off note (get value from
                                ;  port 61h).
        and     al, 11111100b   ; Reset bits 1 and 0.
        out     61h, al         ; Send new value. 
       ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
        mov     ax, 4063       

        out     42h, al         
        mov     al, ah         
        out     42h, al 
        in      al, 61h         
        or      al, 00000011b   
        out     61h, al        
        mov     bx, 25          
pause1:
        mov     cx, 65535
pause2:
        dec     cx
        jne     .pause2
        dec     bx
        jne     .pause1
        in      al, 61h                                     
        and     al, 11111100b  
        out     61h, al               
        ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
         mov     ax, 3043       

        out     42h, al         
        mov     al, ah         
        out     42h, al 
        in      al, 61h         
        or      al, 00000011b   
        out     61h, al        
        mov     bx, 25          
pause1:
        mov     cx, 65535
pause2:
        dec     cx
        jne     .pause2
        dec     bx
        jne     .pause1
        in      al, 61h                                     
        and     al, 11111100b  
        out     61h, al    
        ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
         mov     ax, 3619       

        out     42h, al         
        mov     al, ah         
        out     42h, al 
        in      al, 61h         
        or      al, 00000011b   
        out     61h, al        
        mov     bx, 25          
pause1:
        mov     cx, 65535
pause2:
        dec     cx
        jne     .pause2
        dec     bx
        jne     .pause1
        in      al, 61h                                     
        and     al, 11111100b  
        out     61h, al     
        ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
        mov ah, 2ah                  
        int 21h 
        mov month, ax 
        mov al, dh
```

Comment: Через что предполагается формировать звук ? На сколько я помню если через бипер который на матерях есть (по крайней мере раньше динамик был, сейчас про него как то забывают) то там пара команд in/out в порт управления бипером чуть ли ни готовую частоту задаешь и через другой порт включаешь звук. задержку сам регулируешь и выключаешь. осталось вспомнить как сформулировать вопрос гуглу ... вспомню скажу

Comment: И укажите архитекуру для которой это предполагается, может у вас какой нибудь специализированный контроллер

Comment: Во, вспомнил, он же называется speaker. вот тут прямо с готовым кодом https://courses.engr.illinois.edu/ece390/books/labmanual/io-devices-speaker.html

Comment: @Mike, надо выводить через динамик.

Comment: @Mike, "undeclared label jne .pause2"

Comment: Может вашему ассемблеру не нравятся точки в именах меток. либо вы эту pause2 не написали

Comment: @Mike, убрал точку не помогло. Давайте сначала о паузах, что это за паузи? В коментарие указано "пауза продолжительности заметки", то есть. Если что я вообще не учил паузы. Единственное что, только, когда с AVR имел дело там были задержки "delay". но это ведь не то.

Comment: @Mike, правда убрал точку в строке `.pause1:` и компилится.

Comment: ну пауза в том коде делается тупо холостым циклом 25*65535 раз

Comment: @Mike, правда звука все равно нету.

Comment: @Mike, или есть еще какая-то хитрость?

Comment: Я боюсь вам придется убедится, что динамик к матери подключен и далеко не факт, что эмуляторы умеют эмулировать звук. это надо уточнять в какой нибудь доке на эмулятор. И пробовать без эмулятора, загрузив ваш комп в dos :)

Comment: Если у вас в эмуляторе dos то можете для проверки сделать .bat файл и написать в него `echo 7` только вместо 7 должен быть ascii символ с кодом 7 (набирается Alt+7 на цифровой клавиатуре). ну и запустить этот файл, он должен пропищать. так же в некоторых dos есть команда beep

Comment: @Mike, с вашего позволения буду выражаться прямо. Вы наверняка были студентом и знаете, что такое лабы. Касательно сложившейся ситуации трудно что-то сказать. Я более чем уверен, что вам не верится как можно "изучать Assembler" темпами: сложение значений регистров, перерывания 61h, потом еще что-то, но есть что есть. Давайте я попробую дописать код, который "будет" выводить последовательность. А вы подкорректируете его.

Comment: @Mike, я так понимаю по асемблеру это одна из послдних тем. Так как следующая по функциям, сотоящих из ассемблерных команд в C, там все понятнее.

Comment: Ну студентом я не был. но что такое лаба примерно представляю :) и 61h (если вы про то, что в том коде) это не прерывание, это порт ввода-вывода - окно для доступа процессора к микросхемам матери. Давайте гляну

Comment: А то что вы выложили разве компилится ? Все метки для перехода должны иметь уникальные имена глобально по всему файлу. Так же вижу смысла дублировать весь код несколько раз. по хорошему звук можно и не отключать, один раз включили и только меняем частоты. и когда все завершается выключаем. задание частоты и задержку можно оформить в виде процедуры и вызывать ее с разными частотами. типа `mov ax,4560 / call beep / mov ax,4063 / call beep` и т.п. Или сделать массив с частотами и делать все в цикле беря очередное значение частоты из массива

Comment: @Mike, вы правы, если только ты умеешь это делать. Могу ли попросить вас написать код в ответе? Конечно балы за задание награда сомнительная, но если надо, могу назначить ее. Это, как я уже сказал, последний необходимый код так что сами понимаете.

Comment: http://asmworld.ru/uchebnyj-kurs/021-prostye-procedury/

Comment: старайтесь ограничиваться одной проблемой в каждом вопросе (чтобы ваш вопрос, мог бы кому-нибудь кроме вас пригодиться). Разбейте задачу на несколько: "как нажатие клавиши V зафиксировать", "как вывести текущий месяц", "как одну ноту (261 Гц) проиграть", "как несколько нот проиграть" (зная как проиграть одну ноту). Укажите явно: какая платформа, какой диалект ассемблера.